# ¿Cómo no repetir registros en la Base de Datos?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, laravel, postgresql

Tengo una tabla "cargos" con 2 columnas (id y nombre).
Registro un nombre, ej "ingeniero", entonces luego registro "INGENIERO" e igual la puedo registrar. ¿Cómo podría evitar eso?

No quisiera que me dijeran que registrar todo en mayúsculas en la BD es lo ideal, porque yo quisiera que el usuario tuviera la oportunidad de escoger cómo lo quiere registrar; pero evitando la duplicación de datos.

Estoy trabajando con jQuery, Php, Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las otras respuestas pueden resolver el problema desde la base de datos, pero serían casi incorrectas dentro del contexto de usar un framework, como Laravel en este caso.

Laravel ofrece una herramienta que permite verificar la información recibida en un formulario, y hace el trabajo mucho más sencillo, sin tener que utilizar funciones propias del motor de bases de datos, ni tener que jugar con índices ni sintaxis:

**Validaciones**

Al momento de recibir los datos del usuario, generalmente en el Request (de Laravel) o en el controlador, puedes validar que los datos cumplan con tus estándares, en este caso, que un campo en específico sea único.

Personalmente prefiero que las validaciones se hagan en el Request y no en el controlador, generando dicha validación por medio de artisan e inyectándola como parámetro de entrada del método respectivo en el controlador:

```
php artisan make:request StoreNameRequest
```

en el controlador

```
public function store(StoreNameRequest $request)
{
   //
}
```

Posteriormente en el archivo StoreNameRequest.php, ubicado en el namespace de los Requests, deberías utilizar la validación `unique` para tu campo:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:table,column'
    ];
}
```

La documentación completa está en:

Validaciones en Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

Tipo de validación `unique`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique

Requests: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

---

Edición después de la aclaración en comentarios:

Teniendo en cuenta que no te funciona `unique`, la forma correcta sería crear una validación personalizada para dicho campo, algo como `iunique`, que no sea "case-sensitive" al momento de realizar la comparación.

En todo caso y para responder a tu otra duda, podrías agregar el índice con la función `lower()` que te dieron a la migración así:

```
Schema::table('cargos', function(Blueprint $table){
    $sql = ' CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_lower_unique ON cargos (lower(nombre));';
    DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);
});
```

Comment: Intente de la manera en que explicas pero igual pasa lo que quiero evitar. Lo que quiero es que me registre "ingeniero" y a su vez no me acepte que registre "INGENIERO". Yo quiero prohibir eso.

Comment: Había entendido mal, en todo caso eso es muy fácil, simplemente puedes convertir el valor a "todo en minúsculas" o similar, antes de pasarlo a la validación, en el mismo método `rules()`, a menos que lo quieras validar y registrar, tendríamos que revisar que base de datos estás usando, Postgres es muy potente para hacer comparaciones de este tipo. Ya he tenido problemas similares y he optado por crear mis métodos de validación en Laravel, para que validen sin importar mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Comment: uso Postgres. Peor hasta ahora no se me ocurre algo totalmente optimo :(

Comment: Más tarde te actualizo la solución entonces con lo que necesitas, te lo haré saber con otro comentario.

Comment: ok muchas gracias :D

Comment: Amigo, lo solucione con la respuesta de @Emiliano Torres.

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_lower_unique ON cargos (lower(nombre));

Solo que no se como implementarlo en las migraciones de laravel.

Comment: Aunque no me parece la mejor solución la que te dieron dentro del contexto de Laravel, he agregado el código para que puedas usar ese índice en tu migración.

Comment: y donde esta el código? disculpa soy un poco ignorante.

Comment: ya vi que editaste la publicación, gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes añadir un índice `UNIQUE` a la columna `nombre` de la tabla `cargos`, con lo cual no podrán añadirse dos cargos iguales.

```
ALTER TABLE `cargos` ADD UNIQUE (nombre);
```

En el caso de intentar añadir un valor igual a uno ya insertado, mysql devolvería un error como este:

> 1062 - Duplicate entry 'A' for key 'nombre'

Comment: aprecio la respuesta, pero no es lo que busco. Unique no iguala "ingeniero" a "INGENIERO", los considera distintos para el campo así que los registra.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma fácil podría ser crear un trigger que haga la comprobación haciendo uso de las funciones `UCASE()` o `LCASE()` dentro de la BBDD, y en caso de que ya exista, tira para atrás el cambio.

Answer (score 1):

Agregando el registro UNIQUE es la solución. Pero tienes que ver como está configurada la "collation" de tu base de datos/tabla/field. Para asegurarlo, puedes hacer lo siguiente modificando el field de la tabla y agregando el indice:

```
    ALTER TABLE `cargos` MODIFY `nombre` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
    ALTER TABLE `cargos` ADD UNIQUE (nombre);
```

De esta forma, mysql, comparará de forma binaria los valores para ese campo.
Los "collation" que terminan en _ci son caseinsentive y los que terminan en _cs o sin _ci son casesensitive. Espero te sirva.

Comment: yo uso postgresql :/

Comment: En postgresql puedes probar con la siguiente manera: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_lower_unique 
   ON cargos (lower(nombre));

Comment: Gracias. Me sirvió correctamente. De casualidad sabes como hacerlo en laravel?
Si lo creó
$table->index('nombre')
No lo deja único en la tabla. No se q mas propiedad colocarle, puesto que en la documentación de laravel no veo para hacer lo mismo que hace el código que me pasaste.

Comment: @PabloContreras no he manejado Laravel con postgresql.

Comment: ok gracias. Ya se que se puede y que tengo que buscar la manera de agregarlo con los migrations. Gracias bro.